# Change JComboBox colourms how?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I would like to change the color of the selected combobox.
I do not know name of this event.
It is not a background or foreground, so what then?
More on Image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNIM3.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A renderer works for the items in the dropdown.

The same renderer is also used to render the value displayed in the combo box when the index value is -1. However, the background color is controlled by the UI so you can't just override it. That is the

```
UIManager.getColor("ComboBox.selectionBackground");
```

property is used to control the background so you have a consistent LAF that indicates when the combo box has focus. I don't know of any easy way to control this behaviour. You would need to write a custom UI that sets the background based on the selected value.

Comment: I know it doesn't work, I stated that in my answer. The background color of the renderer is ignored and the background from the UIManager is used that is why you need a custom UI.

Comment: @user3784463 If you are using nimbus, the UI key might be different

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write a new renderer for the combo box.  There are some good examples here:  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AfancyexampleofJComboBoxwithacustomrendererandeditor.htm

Specifically you will be writing a new Cell Renderer.  There's a good tutorial for that here:  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Comboboxcellrenderer.htm

I hope that helps.

Greg

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have my own render, but I do not know how to proceed with the first (selected) row.